# Executing functions conditionally and in parallel

Tags: c#

I have some code that currently looks somewhat like this:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
  MyFunction1,
  MyFunction2,
  MyFunction3,
  MyFunction4,
  MyFunction5);
```

This works really well. Now I also have a list of bytes that's passed in as a parameter and  that looks like this:

```
TheList = new List<Byte>{1, 3, 5, 6 };
```

I want to execute functions based on the content of that list. Let's say that each value of this list is associated to the execution a certain function, like this:

```
1: MyFunction1,
2: MyFunction2,
...
6: MyFunction6
```

The actual names of these functions are different.

How do I change my code so that the function calls get executed in parallel and conditionally to the content of the list of bytes? For instance, if the list contains 1 and 5 then the code will execute only MyFunction1 and MyFunction5, both in parallel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
Dictionary<byte, Action> actions = new Dictionary<byte, Action>()
{
    { 1, MyFunction1 },
    { 2, MyFunction2 },
    ...
    { 6, MyFunction6 }
};

List<byte> actionList = new List<byte>() { 1, 3, 5, 6 };

Parallel.Invoke((from action in actionList select actions[action]).ToArray());
```